# Load stream in Epplus causes disk write error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

Im upload an excel file and trying to load it into a ExcelPackage. Like this

```
public static void ImportStuff(Stream stream)
{
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
   {
     package.Load(stream);
     ...
```

My calling method gets the stream from an uploaded file

```
public  async Task<ActionResult> UploadCsv(int Id, HttpPostedFileBase myfile)
{
    ImportProducts(myfile.InputStream);
}
```

This will cause a A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

Why do a get a write error when I am trying to load something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to upload a csv file. Not a xslx file. Could have hoped for a more descriptive error message but it is working.

Comment: EPPlus claims to support reading CSV. This behavior is a bug.